# Spring Web: disable Jackson converter for specific classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm working on a project that heavily relies on a custom implementation of a Json serializer, deserializer and representation of a json object as a class.
Let's call it `MyJsonClass` as an example.

The problem is, I really need to use a custom `HttpMessageConverter` to convert to/from this Type, because Jackson can't handle it properly.
Adding my own converter before or after Jackson's own ones in the list of converters doesn't seem to prevent the Jackson ones from being tried first. Which will log this error:

```
Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [... MyJsonClass ...]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [...]
```

(`MyJsonClass` extends `Map`)

Being able to actually prevent Jackson from being tried to be used for `application/json` http calls would be great. We don't want to have these useless errors in the logs if things ultimately work (because our `HttpMessageConverter` is used, in the end). We do need Jackson to handle anything that isn't a `Map`, on the other hand.

By what I've seen about custom Jackson deserializers/serializers, they don't leave you full control on the full raw input/output (like HttpMessageConverters do), which is what we need in order to use our Json class.

This is how I register our custom converter in the configuration class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    
        // changing the index doesn't matter
        converters.add(new MyJsonClassHttpMessageConverter());
    
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    }
    
    @Bean
    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer restTemplateBuilderConfigurer) {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = 
                new LinkedList<>(new RestTemplate().getMessageConverters());
    
        // changing the index doesn't matter
        converters.add(new MyJsonClassHttpMessageConverter());
    
        return restTemplateBuilderConfigurer.configure(new RestTemplateBuilder())
                .messageConverters(converters);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I made a class that overrides `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, added it to the list of converters and removed Jackson's own converters.
In the `canRead` and `canWrite` methods of this class I check if the Type is `MyJsonClass` and if so, I return false. This skips using Jackson to try the conversion so my own `HttpMessageConverter` is used instead.

```java
public class MyJsonClassIgnoringMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter 
        extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    public MyJsonClassIgnoringMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Type type, Class<?> contextClass, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (contextClass != null && MyJsonClass.class.isAssignableFrom(contextClass)
                || type == MyJsonClass.class)
            return false;
        return super.canRead(type, contextClass, mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (MyJsonClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
            return false;
        return super.canWrite(clazz, mediaType);
    }
}
```

(I'm sure the above checks could be improved, but they work like this, for me)

In the configuration class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper; // let's use Jackson's properly-configured one

    ...

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    
        replaceJacksonConverters(converters);
    
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    }
    
    @Bean
    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer restTemplateBuilderConfigurer) {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = 
                new LinkedList<>(new RestTemplate().getMessageConverters());
    
        replaceJacksonConverters(converters);
    
        return restTemplateBuilderConfigurer.configure(new RestTemplateBuilder())
                .messageConverters(converters);
    }

    ...

    private void replaceJacksonConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        for (int i = converters.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (converters.get(i) instanceof AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                converters.remove(i);
        }
        // the custom HttpMessageConverter that can properly serialize and deserialize MyJsonClass
        converters.add(new MyJsonClassHttpMessageConverter());
        // the custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter defined above
        converters.add(new MyJsonClassIgnoringMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
    }

}
```

The reason why I didn't define the `MyJsonClassIgnoringMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` as a `@Bean` is that not all Spring classes that add the original one to the list do it by taking it as a bean. Most of them just do "new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()"... so since I'd need to replace it anyway like I did above with that `replaceJacksonConverters` method, I figured I didn't really need it as a bean.